# Response from AWS to variable

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am new in shell scripting and I want to write response from amazon event to a variable

I've tried this

```
response=`aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name vpn --log-stream-name 111 --log-events file://$FILE_name$d.json --sequence-token 49590180452461598387117663617675757188621681936165781314`
```

end run echo "response" - a see empty string in terminal

please help me get the response to variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last "`"

with " 2>&1`" (with a leading white space) to get stdout and stderr to your variable.

Comment: like that ->. response= `aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name vpn --log-stream-name 111 --log-events file://$FILE_name$d.json --sequence-token 49590180452461598387117663617675757188621681936165781314>&1` ?

Comment: Thanks - solved.  response=`aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name vpn --log-stream-name 111 --log-events file://$FILE_name$d.json --sequence-token 49590180452461598387117663617675757188621681936165781314 2>&1`

Comment: Yes, with a leading white space. I've updated my answer.